# Unittesting a builder method

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have implemented a new class, Holder. The following are the objectives:

1. Three fields. Field 1 and 2 are ints and field 3 is a boolean.
2. Once constructed, it shall not change (immutable). Therefore the fields will have getters only.
3. Fields 1 and 2 are initialised by extracting information from 5 possible types, string format 1, string format 2, int, class type A and class type B. Field 3 is set as true / false.

The problem that this leaves me with is that there are 50 possible constructor options. 5 X 5 X 2. This isn't sensible or scalable (add a 6th type and I'd have to write a huge change), so I used a builder pattern:

```
class Builder {
    Builder s1SetField1(String Format1),
    Builder s2SetField1(String Format2),
    ...
    Builder s1SetField2(String Format1),
    ...
    Builder setField3(boolean b)
    Holder build()
}
```

This works really well. I have 5 builder methods for field 1 initialisation, 5 builder methods for field 2 initialisation and one for the boolean. Once the fields are set, call the build() method which calls the private constructor with the correctly formatted fields and return a new object.

The problem that I have is unittesting. I would like to set up a list populated with a representative object built with every permutation of the Builder methods. Now I'm back to 50 new Build() calls.
I thought about creating 3 lists - field1List, field2List and field3List. then, hierarchically iterate through each one:

```
for (Object f1 : field1List) {
    for (Object f2 : field2List) {
        for (boolean f3 : field3List) {
            returnList.add(new Builder().setField1(f1).setField2(f2).setField3(f3).build());
        }
    }
}
return returnList;
```

Of course, holding mixed Object in a lists just seems clunky. Is there a better way to initialise using every permutation?

Comment: Why do you need to test every permutation? Why don't you test each setXxx() method of the builder separately, and then test the build method?

Comment: I've simplified this example quite a bit. There are some builder rules in the background that says how setField1 and setField2 are interpreted, based on the state of the other and the boolean, when the build() is called.

Comment: @JBNizet is definitely on the right track here - looks like you need to be able to decompose the problem to allow testing of the different parts separately. It may be that a different approach would make it easier to tests different pieces in isolation - though hard to say what that may be without a more detailed example to understand how the different field builders interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to test every permutation of inputs to a system is madness. For even small systems the  number of permutations is huge.

Instead use *equivalence partitioning* to classify those many permutations into a smaller set of *equivalence classes*, and have only one test case per equivalence class. Use your knowledge of the problem your code is solving and the way it is written (or likely to be written,  if you are testing someone else's code) to choose a set of equivalence classes that have the property that, if the program works correctly for one test case in the equivalence class, if is *very likely* to work correctly for all the other cases in the class. This gives cost effective test cases.

In your case, I'd test the `build ()` alone, plus one test for each of the `setXXX ()` methods followed by the `build ()` method.